# Async loop with flatMap

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

I want to insert a lot of sample data asynchronously. I used this code:

```
def insertSampleData(count: Int): Future[LastError] = {
  if (count > 0) {
    val future = defaultService.save(... /*sample data*/)

    future flatMap { _ =>
      insertSampleData(count - 1)
    }
  } else {
    Future.successful(.../* Empty */)
  }
}

val result = insertSampleData(1000000) map { _ =>
  "Inserted"
}
```

`result` is a `Future[String]` which returns "Inserted" when all items are inserted.

Is is OK regarding performance? and is there any other way to do that?

Comment: As written, this will make the calls to `defaultService.save` in sequence.  Is this a requirement, or did you want to run them in parallel?

Comment: No, running in parallel is very nice but not 1000000 parallel saves. As I know `par` will work base on CPU core count which sounds good.